# Problem with F# Interactive and Plotly (XPlot)

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, plotly, f#-interactive

After installing XPlot and Plotly on VS Code on a new machine, they no longer work properly. When creating a line chart in F# Interactive, the following shows up in the terminal window:

```
Binding session to '...\xplot.plotly\4.0.6\lib\netstandard2.0\XPlot.Plotly.dll'...                  [XPlot.Plotly.Scatter]                                    
Binding session to '...\newtonsoft.json\12.0.3\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'...             val it: unit = ()
```

If sending the Plotly chart to Chart.Show, the following output is generated:

```
[XPlot.Plotly.Scatter]                                    
val it: PlotlyChart =                                     
  XPlot.Plotly.PlotlyChart                                
    {Height = 500;                                        
     Id = "57f554e5-ba40-458f-a68d-8ff99447e928";         
     PlotlySrc = "https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js";                                                        
     Width = 900;}
```

Why isn't F# Interactive opening and displaying the chart in a new browser window?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is that the new version (or the way you are loading it) no logner registers the automatic printer for Plotly charts that would display them when they get evaluated in F# Interactive (this was always a bit tricky and it can only be done in a script if you load Plotly via `#load` but it cannot be done if you reference it e.g. via `#r "nuget:XPlot.Plotly"`.

You can workaround this by explicitly calling `Show`:

```
#r "nuget:XPlot.Plotly"
open XPlot.Plotly

Chart.Line [ for x in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 6.4 -> x, sin x ]
|> Chart.Show
```

Or you can register a printer yourself:

```
fsi.AddPrinter(fun (pc:PlotlyChart) -> pc.Show(); "(Plotly chart)")

// Show is not needed anymore
Chart.Line [ for x in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 6.4 -> x, sin x ]
```

**EDIT:** If the above does not work, then you can try looking at what's going wrong with the code for `Show`. You can fairly easily extract this from the Plotly source - a standalone version looks like this:

```
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

let showInBrowser (c:PlotlyChart) =
    let pageId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    let tempPath = Path.GetTempPath()
    let file = sprintf "%s.html" pageId
    let path = Path.Combine(tempPath, file)
    let html = c.GetHtml()
    File.WriteAllText(path, html)
    if RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) then
        let psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(FileName = path, UseShellExecute = true)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi) |> ignore
    elif RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) then
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("xdg-open", path) |> ignore
    elif RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX) then
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("open", path) |> ignore
    else
        invalidOp "Not supported OS platform"

Chart.Line [ for x in 0.0 .. 0.1 .. 6.4 -> x, sin x ]
|> showInBrowser
```

Try playing with this to see where it goes wrong - does it save the file to TEMP correctly or not? Does the code to open the browser then fail?

Comment: Alas, neither of the above works, same issue remains. Chart.Show returns nothing, no action, while Chart.Line simply returns the chart object...

Comment: @LocoBarocco That's odd - see EDIT for some hint on how to debug this..

Comment: Just tried, same problem as before, browser not opening at all. Strangely, Plotly.Interactive works fine in Polyglot Notebook. Checked the temp folder and the chart html file has indeed been saved there! Just wondering why the browser is not being launched?

Comment: I ran your latest script again - now all of a sudden both your showInBrowser as well as the old Chart.Show works! Have no idea why though, could it have been something related to user access to the temp folder?